# I want to write in an embed the postion of the role compared to the role position+1 and role position -1

Tags: discord.js, roles

```
{name:"Position",value: interaction.guild.roles.cache.filter(role.position+1||role.position||role.position-1).map(m=>m).join(" => ")})
```

i try to map the role position +1 , role position and role position -1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues..
`<Collection>#filter`'s First option is a callback function, not a comparison like you're doing.
Second what you *are* doing while logically saying "or" makes sense the way node will interpret it is `true || true || true` as the comparison operator will convert the numeric role position value to a boolean, which if greater than 0 will be true. The proper way to do something like this would be:

```js
interaction.guild.roles.cache.filter(filterRole => 
  role.position === filterRole.position - 1 ||
  role.position === filterRole.position ||
  role.position === filterRole.position + 1
)
```

Comment: this work but this put them in alphabetic order